# Triggering the Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) 'acf/save_post' Action

Tags: wordpress, hook, action, advanced-custom-fields

I've read the ACF 'acf/save_post' documentation here: [acf-save_post<sup>Docs</sup>](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-save_post/), which states this action enables one to add additional functionally before or after saving/updating a post. I want to test when this action is triggered.

I created a custom post type and a collection of ACF custom fields that are linked to this custom post type.This includes some ACF custom field types that I created using the ACF Starter Kit (see: [creating-a-new-field-type<sup>Docs</sup>](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/creating-a-new-field-type/)), and they are used for some of the ACF custom fields. When I edit a custom post and then click the 'Update' button in the Gutenberg editor, I expect the 'acf/save_post' action to fire, but it does not seem to do so. Perhaps I am missing something. Here is the relevant code from my theme's 'function.php' file.

```
function my_acf_save_post($post_id) {
  console_log("Testing...");
}
add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post', 20);

function console_log($output, $with_script_tags = true) {
  $js_code = 'console.log(' . json_encode($output, JSON_HEX_TAG) . ')';

  if($with_script_tags) {
    $js_code = '<script>' . $js_code . '</script>';
  }

  echo $js_code;
}
```

*Citation for the 'console_log' function: Kim Sia (see: https://stackify.com/how-to-log-to-console-in-php/).*

I have my web browser's inspector window opened for my custom post type post's editor. After modifying the post and clicking 'Update', nothing displays in the inspector's console pane. I posted about this in the ACF forum but have received no response.

Your feedback is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Anthony, I´ve used this hook many times and it definitely works. Are you adding your code to a file in your theme called function.php? Are you sure this is the active theme? And also, can you try renaming it functions.php, in plural and test again?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Tami. On the latter point, I made a typo in my post; the file name is 'functions.php'. Yes, I am using the active theme's 'functions.php' file. Have you used this action within the context of a custom post type? I had another version of the code that first checks the post type via a conditional, but the problem remained. Can you try my code in your environment and see if the 'console.log' statement prints to your web browser inspector panel's 'Console' pane? Much appreciated.

Comment: Hey Anthony, thanks for the update. I was just checking the obvious mistakes first! Yes, I have used the hook with custom post types. Your way of debugging to the console is a bit strange, would you like to first check if the issue is in your console log function first, to at least discard it from the equation? I would use WP's in built debugger, and can help you set it up if you don't know how.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Tami. You're right. I narrowed down the JSON response message error to the 'echo console.log...' line of code in the 'console_log) function. I changed the code from "echo $js_code;" to "echo 'console.log(' . json_encode($age) .')';", but that did not work either.

I enabled the WP debugger in the "wp-config.php" file. There seems to be no way to assert an error for testing purposes, but, then again, I am not well-versed in the WP debugger.

I would appreciate your thoughts on the WP debugger's practical use. How do you implement it in your work? Thank you.

Comment: Sometimes I'm right! Yes, I think I can definitely help you, but I'm not with a computer right now. I'll post my answer for you in a little while when I get back, ok?

Answer (score 1):

Find below the instructions of how to debug that ACF hook in WordPress.
Official document for further details: https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/

Note that there are other, more sophisticated and efficient ways of debugging in WordPress, for example using a proper debugger like xdebug.

These are usually harder to setup though, so here I am giving you the "WordPress in-built" way that might be simple, but is easy and effective.

**ENABLE DEBUGGING**

First, you need to enable debugging in wp-config.php, which I think you already did, but for others reading this answer, what you should do is:

1. Open in a text editor the file called wp-config.php, located in the wordpress installation root
2. Add the following to this file:

   **define('WP_DEBUG', true);**  => This enables debugging

   **define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);** => This prevents error logging from displaying on screen (affects both frontend and backend)

   **define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);** => This logs the output to a file where you can then check it

You must add these yes or yes above the line
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

Done! Now you are logging, by default, to a file that will get generated in the root of the wp-content directory named **debug.log**.

WARNING! It is recommended to not leave debugging enabled on Production environments, as well as it is recommended to not leave the debug.log file as it could leave sensible site information exposed. Use for development only, and disable and remove file when finished. File can also be saved to a custom file name and location, see docs.

**ERROR LOG**

console.log is usually used for debugging js.

To log your function in PHP using the enabled debugger above, do the following:

```
function my_acf_save_post($post_id) {
   
   error_log( 'Saved post ID : ' . $post_id, false);
   error_log( var_export($_POST, true), false );

   //If you want to log what got saved to the database
   error_log( var_export(get_post($post_id), true), false );

}
add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post', 20);
```

You should find the saved post data and the ACF data recorded in a file named debug.log in your wp-content directory root.

**LOGGING TO SCREEN**

If instead what you want is to see the output that would have got written to the file, but directly on the screen, you don't need error_log() function, and instead you do that as shown below:

```
function my_acf_save_post($post_id) {
   
   echo 'Saved post ID : ' . $post_id;
  
   // Add <pre> tags to format the output in an easily readable way:
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($_POST);
   echo '</pre>';
}
add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post', 20);
```

Comment: Thank you again, Tami. I appreciate your detailed response. I previously read WP's official debugging documentation but overlooked the important "error_log" function. For now, I deactivated my WP debugger plugins and modified my "wp-config.php" file to let WP natively handle debugging. I have a question about the "WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY" configuration. I opted in. However, error_log only generates log messages to a file or via email. My error does not appear in the HTML post edit page where the error occurs. How do I ensure an error message appears in my post's editor page, where the error exists?

Comment: You're welcome @AnthonyPetosa About your questions above, I think the issue is you have a couple of misconceptions that I will try to clarify. First error_log() function does not log strictly "errors" only, it logs anything you indicate it to log. Second, "WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY" has no relation to showing the output from functions like error_log() on screen, all it does is print on screen actual errors (PHP Critical errors and warnings), but not specific output you want to see. If what you want is a combination of the two, and print your desired output to screen, please check the updated answer.

Comment: Let me know how it goes! And please "accept" the answer, if you think it has correctly provided a solution to your problem :)

Comment: Yes, I realize the "error_log" function writes to an external log file, and those messages may be notices, errors, etc. I also know that the "WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY" directive writes to screen. However, as I noted in my previous comment, when I enable this directive, nothing is written to my post editor page, where the error originates. I would expect WP to print an error to screen on the page via which the error is generated. What am I missing?

Comment: You can try adding @ini_set('display_errors',0); to wp-config.php

Comment: Thank you. I added "@ini_set('display_errors, 1);" to wp-config.php, because I want to enable the setting. Also, I restarted my local server after having updated wp-config.php. Unfortunately, this did not solve the issue.

Comment: Can you describe again what the issue is exactly at this point? What are you trying to log that is not displaying? Also, as a quick test, try adding wp_die(); at the end of your function to see if it does what you're after?